# Django dev server using old version of views.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

For some reason, the changes I make on the views.py file are not being reflected. I initially made a function inside view.py to return `HttpResponse(request.POST.items())`. Even after making changes to the function, it's still performing the same thing. I tried clearing the cache of the browser, restarted the server, and also tried deleting the pyc files. Nothing worked. Any guess on why this is happening?

urls.py

```
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
path('proceedaction/<str:pk>/',views.ProceedAction.as_view(),name='proceedaction'),

    path('uploadct/<str:pk>/',views.UploadCT.as_view(),name='uploadct'),



]

views.py

from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views import View
from .models import CreatePatient,PatientRecord,FileData
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .filters import RecordFilter
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
        return render(request,'index.html')

class UploadCT(View,LoginRequiredMixin):
        def get(self,request,pk):
            records = PatientRecord.objects.filter(id=pk)
            context={
            'record' : records,
             }
             return render(request,'ct_upload.html',context=context)

        def post(self,request):
            dbdata = FileData()
            return redirect('index')
```

Comment: Not sure about how to answer this question but if you can add full view function and urls.py will help.

Comment: Updated the question with extracts from views.py and urls.py

Comment: Solved the problem. I hadn't specified method = POST in HTML form after making a few updates.

Answer (score 0):

I had not specified method=POST in the corresponding HTML file. Solved this issue by doing that.